# Creating updating time and date function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been testing basic skills in JavaScript and jQuery.
I decided to create a updating clock for a page. First day I didn't read up at all, unless it was stuck on a function name. My first attempt was rash and had such a massive amount of code.

*(Quick note: I did finish my first attempt, however I didn't save it, this was mid process of fixing a bug)*

Today I did a little reading before creating my function. Here are both functions I created:

```
setInterval(updateTime, 1);

function updateTime() {
    var clock = new Date();
    var dayNum = Number(clock.getDay());
    var hour = clock.getHours();
    var min = clock.getMinutes();
    var sec = clock.getSeconds();

    var day = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

    function getDay() {
        return day[dayNum - 1];
    }

    function getHour() {
        if (hour > 12) {
            var yes = hour - 12;
            return yes + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "pm";
        } else {
            return yes + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "am";
        }
    }

    function setTime() {
        $(".clock").text(getDay() + " " + getHour());
    }

    var clock = {};
    return setTime();
}
```

```
setInterval(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    $("#time").text(date.toLocaleTimeString());
    $("#date").text(date.toDateString());
}, 500);
```

Can my second attempt be more optimised?

Comment: Please show us your desired output. Otherwise it is hard to say...

Comment: The Date "Thu May 02 2019" was trivial.

Comment: Just the "11:37:02" was the desired output